What is the best way to listen to solana events on localnet? (not devnet or mainnet)
What is the best way to listen to solana events on localnet? (not devnet or mainnet)
I know there are ways to do this with Helius on devnet and mainnet, but what about those that are building net new functionality on local test validator?

I might be misunderstanding the question, but localnet works just like any other network, so you can create websocket subscriptions, same as you would with devnet or mainnet.
